# How can I access an webpage's resources when I browse it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

This is the situation. With Google Chrome's "Inspect element" feature, I can view the resources of a webpage I visit. It has JavaScript and I want to edit it to modify how it is displayed in my browser. Is it even possible? Then how can I do it?

Comment: [http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html)

Comment: Are you trying to manually edit the page or do you want a Chrome extension that will always modify the page when viewed?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, muntasir2000!

Here is the documentation from http://code.google.com/ : http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Comment: @muntasir2000 you can accept this as an answer, if it answered your question (just click the tick below the down arrow on the left side of my answer)